# Sum of: k permutations of n $\times e^x$

Tags: permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

Simplify the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{\ell =1}^n P(n,\ell) (e^x -1)^\ell
\end{equation}

to something like $n!n^n$. I got curious about this expression after going through this answer: math.stackexchange.com/q/3076350.

Comment: What's $P(n,\ell)$?

Comment: There is not sufficient information here to answer this question.

Comment: @Wojowu it represents the $\ell$ permutations of n, i.e., $P(n,\ell) = \dfrac{n!}{n-\ell !}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{l=1}^n {n! \over (n-k)!} (e^x -1)^l =$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{e^x-1}} \left(e^x-1\right)^n \Gamma \left(n+1,\frac{1}{-1+e^x}\right)-1$$

Comment: So there *is* sufficient information to answer this question, it seems :P

Comment: @Wojowu:  Well yes... once one guesses the meaning of your terms (which does not match your title).